# Side Panel in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div called calendar that is inside a div called cal-container. The calendar has width:100% so currently it takes up the whole cal-container.

I need to add a side-panel div. This div will have a fixed width of `150 pixels`. Thus, #calendar width should be #cal-container width - 150px. Is this possible with CSS or am I forced to use a table?

If it is possible, is there an example? I googled it but nothing like what I want came up.
The side-panel can be hidden and shown by click a button so adding padding will not work.

Here is an idea of what I mean:
The days part is #calendar, and the Unscheduled part is the side panel of 150px.

I tried floating the calendar left, and cloating the side panel right and giving it a width of 150px. But the idea is if I hide that div, the calendar should then take 100%.

[image]
Thanks

Like this, the blue would be side and calendar be the left, but calendar needs to take up the room side does not when hidden.
http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/finished.html

Result of float:
[image]

Comment: Any [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Like this, the blue would be side and calendar be the left, but calendar needs to take up the room side does not when hidden.
http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/finished.html

Comment: A calendar is pretty much tabular data so using a table for the calendar structure wouldn't be such a terrible thing imo.

Comment: The calendar IS a table, just think of it as needing 2 divs, width of A is parent - B width. B width is variable.

Comment: if you outline the calendar and the side panel and set this container to a specific width (e.g. 1000px) and position relative you know that the side panel is 15% of 1000px so the rest of the width (calendar) will automatically fill the rest up

Comment: The container width must be variable.

Comment: Think of it as a variable page width with a fixed side column.

Comment: you could use float and set the calendar to float left and the panel to float right no?

Comment: Any other styles I should set? Tried this but it had not worked.

Comment: Floating works, but then my calendar dies not span the page:

Comment: Will try it for you later this day if not yet solved

Comment: See above for what floating does. It almost works, but does not span the whole page height now.

Comment: try a clearfix e.g. <container><left element>left</left element><right element>right</right element><div style="clear:both"></container>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Got a working solution for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/W4hwt/).

The code to get this working basically hinges on the following structure:

```
<div class="sideBar">
  ...
</div>
<div class="tableWrapper">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Next, make sure the elements have these significant CSS properties:

```
.sideBar {
  float: right;
}

.tableWrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

What's happening here is that the `.sideBar` floats right, and takes up whatever space it needs to. Meanwhile, the `.tableWrapper` will take up whatever space is left by virtue of `overflow: hidden`. Finally, tell the `table` to take up 100% of its available width.

Click the button in the demo to see the table automatically resize.

Answer (score 0):

All major browsers and IE10 support [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/). Not supported < IE10.